# Doubt in proof of Jordan - von Neumann theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

In Paliogiannis and Martin A. Moskowitz's *Functions Of Several Real Variables*, the Jordan - von Neumann theorem is given as follows:
[image]
The inner product is defined as: $$\langle x,y \rangle = \frac{||x+y||^2-||x-y||^2}{4}$$
For proving $\langle cx,y \rangle = c\langle x,y \rangle  $, the book describes the following step:
[image]
The reasoning behind it is not clear to me. I am aware of the method which was used in original paper to prove this ie. first proving it for $c \in \mathbb{Q}$ and using the continuity of norm and density of $\mathbb{Q}$ to prove for $c \in \mathbb{R}$. But I wanted to see if there is an easier way which the book intends to convey. I tried a lot of different manipulations but to no avail.

I'm just curious whether there is some other method which this book wants to convey or is it just a genuine oversight? I found an errata for this book, but it had no mention of this theorem.

Comment: Where do you find the errata?

Comment: @Hamilton here https://github.com/tadejpetric/functions_of_several_real_variables_errata/blob/master/errata.csv

Answer (score -1):

The way he proved $\langle cx, y \rangle = c \langle x, y
\rangle$, for $c \in \mathbb{R}$

In this step: $\langle cx, y\rangle = \frac14 [||cx+y||^2 - ||cx- y ||^2]$. The author used his definition of the inner product.

As for $\frac14 [||cx+y||^2 - ||cx- y ||^2] = \frac14 [4c\langle x, y\rangle]$, It seems there is a gap there. We need to evoke the parallelogram law to reach there.

Comment: I am aware of the Polarization identity. Isn't it for norms induced from inner product? In my question, I am constructing an inner product from a norm. So it is not clear to me, how we can use it.

Comment: The formula about norms induced from inner products is just $|| x || = \langle x, x \rangle$. This is not Polarization identity.

Comment: Ok but how does it help to get RHS?

Comment: @AjinShajiJose What do mean by RHS? I update my answer does it make sense to you now?

Comment: @Hamilton  Where you say in your argument "just use the definition of the norm from the inner product" you're illegitimately *assuming* that the norm has already been defined in terms of an inner product, whereas the hypotheses of the theorem are merely that the norm satisfies the requirements needed for $\ V\ $ to be a normed vector space (not necessarily an inner product space), and the parallelogram law, $\ \|x+y\|^2+$$\,\|x-y\|^2$$\,=2\big(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2\big)\ $, *without necessarily* having been defined in terms of an inner product.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Yes you are right, I modified my stetament